# Group by the results as multidimensional array

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, group-by

I have requirement to get data grouped by `created_date` and then again groped this result set data on `affiliate_ad`. I am using this

```
 return DB::table($this->table)
      ->whereRaw($where['rawQuery'], isset($where['bindParams']) ? $where['bindParams'] : array())
      ->select('id', 'created_date','affiliate_ad', DB::raw('count(*) as total,count(affiliate_ad=1) as affiliate_ad_count,SUBSTRING(`created_date`, 1, 10) AS c_date'))
      ->groupBy('affiliate_ad','c_date')
      ->orderBy('c_date', 'desc')
      ->get();
```

It's giving me result like this

```
 Collection {#385
   #items: array:18 [
    0 => {#386
      +"id": 354766
      +"created_date": "2018-01-10 10:16:27"
      +"affiliate_ad": 1
      +"total": 2
      +"affiliate_ad_count": 1
      +"c_date": "2018-01-10"
    }
    1 => {#384
      +"id": 354730
      +"created_date": "2018-01-10 10:10:39"
      +"affiliate_ad": 0
      +"total": 3
      +"affiliate_ad_count": 4
      +"c_date": "2018-01-10"
    }
    2 => {#387
      +"id": 338263
      +"created_date": "2018-01-08 10:10:52"
      +"affiliate_ad": 0
      +"total": 83
      +"affiliate_ad_count": 83
      +"c_date": "2018-01-08"
    }
  ]
}
```

Here if you check, in the first two index the created date is same. So i want to group them in one array index at `0th` index as `multidimensional array` grouped on `affiliate_ad`. The actual query is build as

```
SELECT id
     , created_date
     , affiliate_ad
     , COUNT(*) total
     , COUNT(affiliate_ad = 1) affiliate_ad_count
     , SUBSTRING(created_date,1,10) c_date 
  FROM facebook_ad 
 WHERE facebook_id = 12345 
   AND reward_status = 0 
   AND (first_seen BETWEEN 0 AND 99999999) 
 GROUP 
    BY affiliate_ad
     , c_date 
 ORDER 
    BY c_date desc
```

I need the output like this

```
Collection {#385
   #items: array:18 [
    0 => [
        0 => {#386
          +"id": 354766
          +"created_date": "2018-01-10 10:16:27"
          +"affiliate_ad": 1
          +"total": 2
          +"affiliate_ad_count": 1
          +"c_date": "2018-01-10"
       }
       1 => {#384
          +"id": 354730
          +"created_date": "2018-01-10 10:10:39"
          +"affiliate_ad": 0
          +"total": 3
          +"affiliate_ad_count": 4
          +"c_date": "2018-01-10"
        }
    ]
    1 => [
        0 => {#387
          +"id": 338263
          +"created_date": "2018-01-08 10:10:52"
          +"affiliate_ad": 0
          +"total": 83
          +"affiliate_ad_count": 83
          +"c_date": "2018-01-08"
        }
   ]
  ]
}
```

I have these data in mysql 
[image: MySql Data Screenshot]

Comment: Your query is invalid because you are selecting non aggregate columns.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen may you correct me, what is need to be added here

Comment: Let's gst the query squared away.  Show us sample input data and the output you expect.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I have edited my question to add the actual query, please check

Comment: This edit doesn't help much.  Basically your query is invalid and I'm not sure what to suggest because of this.

Comment: Can you give an example of the result you want?

Comment: if your only_full_group_by is disabled the query only returns first unique rows based on groupBy parameters. if you want to get count of result or sum of a column you are in wrong way! if you want to use aggregate operations you should use nested selects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get similar to image below

[image]

You may consider to format it after you get your results from your query. It already returned you a collection. you may add `->groupBy('c_date')->values()` to collection to retrieve the given result. If you remove `->values()` part it will preserve grouped dates as key.

Comment: Yeah i did the same, but i want to do it using mysql query

Comment: @RAUSHANKUMAR With MySQL you can not return such structures.

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
count(affiliate_ad=1)
```

to

```
SUM(affiliate_ad=1)
```

if you want to 'count' the number of rows where `affiliate_ad` is `1`.

That is, `COUNT` ignores what you put in the parens unless it is a column.  In that case it counts how many rows are have that column `NOT NULL`.  `COUNT(DISTINCT col)` does a different thing.

`SUM(expression)` evaluates the expression and adds up the values.  If `expression` is Boolean (eg, `affiliate_ad=1`), then TRUE is treated as 1 and FALSE is treated as 0.  Hence, it gives you the 'count' you probably want.

Beware of how `NULLs` are counted/summed/averaged.

Answer (score 2):

Too long for a comment, but something quite important to consider...

```
SELECT * FROM ints;
+---+
| i |
+---+
| 0 |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 5 |
| 6 |
| 7 |
| 8 |
| 9 |
+---+

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ints;
+----------+
| COUNT(*) |
+----------+
|       10 |
+----------+

SELECT COUNT(i=1) FROM ints;
+------------+
| COUNT(i=1) |
+------------+
|         10 |
+------------+
```

Comment: I add the screenshot of my data in question, please check how it is and what result i am expecting?

Comment: I don't do screenshots

Answer (score 2):

Seeing as `id` is unique and you're selecting it individually, it won't be grouped in your results. If you need the individual ID's as well as the other data you're returning, I'd suggest using `GROUP_CONCAT(id)`.

See here for more: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Not sure if this fully answers your question, but hope it helps point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

```
return DB::table($this->table)
      ->whereRaw($where['rawQuery'], isset($where['bindParams']) ? $where['bindParams'] : array())
      ->select('id', 'created_date','affiliate_ad', DB::raw('count(*) as total,count(affiliate_ad=1) as affiliate_ad_count,SUBSTRING(`created_date`, 1, 10) AS c_date'))
      ->groupBy('affiliate_ad','c_date')
      ->orderBy('c_date', 'desc')
      ->get()->groupBy('affiliate_ad');
```

This will work for you if you get error in your **config/database.php** change

```
strict => false,
```

Answer (score 2):

The way you want to use group by works only on aggregates in MySQL, like `SUM` or `MAX`, etc.

You can do something like this, though I haven't tested it, when you fetch your results from the database do the following:

```
$results->groupBy('affiliate_ad');

foreach ($results as $i => $ad_group) {
    foreach ($ad_group as $items) {
        $results[$i] = (new Collection($items))->groupBy('c_date');  
    }
}
```

NOTE: depending of the version of Laravel `DB` returns an array or a `Collection` object, if it returns an array in your version put it in a collection object like this `new \Illuminate\Support\Collection($results)`